Error users.findOne con conexión a base de usuarios de mongo mediante URI
estuve haciendo algunos cambios en mi proyecto de la facu para poder separar la lógica de negocio de las operaciones de acceso a datos siguiendo el modelo de capas (DAO) y la conexión con el cluster de mongoDB dejo de funcionar, cuando intento loguearme con un usuario ya registrado me tira este error:
Servidor Express iniciado en el puerto: 8080
Error al iniciar sesión: MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\roman\OneDrive\Escritorio\Programador\Backend\Tareas y proyectos\Proyecto\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
Códigos:
.env: (raíz del proyecto):
PORT=8080
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://admin:************@cluster0.rcj2pgu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

src/config/config.js:
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 8080,
  MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI
};

database.js: (raíz del proyecto):
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/config');

const uri = config.MONGODB_URI;

console.log('Intentando conectar a MongoDB con la URI:', uri);

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 60000, //Aqui intente aumentar a 1m pero  no funciona
  socketTimeoutMS: 60000,          
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Conexión exitosa a MongoDB Atlas');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error al conectar a MongoDB Atlas:', error);
  });

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (error) => console.error('Error de conexión MongoDB:', error));
db.on('disconnected', () => console.log('Se ha perdido la conexión a MongoDB'));
db.on('reconnected', () => console.log('Se ha restablecido la conexión a MongoDB'));
db.once('open', () => console.log('Conexión a MongoDB establecida'));

module.exports = mongoose;

app.js: (raíz del proyecto):
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const passport = require('passport');
const GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;
const config = require('./config/config');


// Middleware para inicializar sesiones
app.use(session({
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: config.MONGODB_URI, // Usar la variable de entorno MONGODB_URI desde config.js
    ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 14 dias de duracion de sesion
  }),
  secret: 'mi-secreto',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));

Quizá alguien pueda visualizar algún error que yo por mi inexperiencia no. Gracias :)
